# Laravel Eloquent : Get records according to day and month

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get records whose birthday is `today, today + 1, today + 2`.

Suppose someone is born on 16-05-1991.
I've to find those records whose birthday is today, tomorrow, and day after tomorrow

```
$todayDate = date('Y-m-d');
$toDate1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($todayDate . ' + 1 days'));
$toDate2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($todayDate . ' + 2 days'));
```

I tried to use `orWhereDay, orWhereMonth` but it doesn't make sense.

Edit : I've done like this but I'm looking for a more efficient way to do this.
https://pastebin.com/GRdRH2jC

Comment: Have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 0):

The correct code seems to be

```
 $date = new DateTime;
 $date2 = $date->modify('+1 day');
 $date3 = $date->modify('+2 day');
 $formatted_date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
 $formatted_date2 = $date2->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
 $formatted_date3 = $date3->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Tinker output

```
>>> $date = new DateTime;
=> DateTime @1558028326 {#3144
     date: 2019-05-16 17:38:46.169709 UTC (+00:00),
   }
>>> $date2 = $date->modify('+1 day');
=> DateTime @1558114726 {#3144
     date: 2019-05-17 17:38:46.169709 UTC (+00:00),
   }
>>> $date3 = $date->modify('+2 day');
=> DateTime @1558287526 {#3144
     date: 2019-05-19 17:38:46.169709 UTC (+00:00),
   }
>>> $formatted_date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
=> "2019-05-19 17:38:46"
>>> $formatted_date2 = $date2->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
=> "2019-05-19 17:38:46"
>>> $formatted_date3 = $date3->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
=> "2019-05-19 17:38:46"
>>>
```

Using Carbon

```
>>> $today = Carbon\Carbon::now()
=> Carbon\Carbon @1558072952 {#3119
     date: 2019-05-17 06:02:32.343195 UTC (+00:00),
   }
>>> $date2 = $today->addDay();
=> Carbon\Carbon @1558159352 {#3119
     date: 2019-05-18 06:02:32.343195 UTC (+00:00),
   }
>>> $date3 = $today->addDays(2);
=> Carbon\Carbon @1558332152 {#3119
     date: 2019-05-20 06:02:32.343195 UTC (+00:00),
   }
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Carbon class for time, makes things a bit easier

```
Use Carbon/Carbon

$today = Carbon::now()->today();
$toDate1 = Carbon::now()->today()->addDays(1);
$todate2 = Carbon::now()->today()->addDays(2);
$todate2 = Carbon::now()->today()->addDays(3);

where('birthday, '>', $today)->where('birthday', '<', $toDate1); //today
where('birthday, '>', $toDate1)->where('birthday', '<', $toDate2); //today + 1
where('birthday, '>', $toDate2)->where('birthday', '<', $toDate3); //today + 2
```

if you just want month and day then you can do it like this

```
 $today = Carbon::now()->today()->format('m-d');
```

Comment: do i've to use three different query ?

Comment: if you need separate birthdates for each dates then yes, if you want all birthdates in just one query then you only need to use one where `where('birthday, '>', $today)->where('birthday', '<', $toDate3)`

Comment: suppose today is 31st of May, then tomorrow will be a new month, don't you think I've to use month too.

Comment: also if someones b'day is 01/01/1991, I think the queries you mentioned will not work.

Comment: you'll need to set the year too

Comment: `Carbon::now()->today()->subYear()` like this

Answer (score -1):

```
$upcomingBdays = model::select('id', ... , 'birthday')->get()->filter(function ($model) {
    // get the bday and change the year to this year so we can simply compare dates
    $bday = Carbon::parse($model->birthday)->year(today()->year); // you can skip parsing if you have the field in the protected $dates on model
    return $bday->between(today(), today()->addDays(2));
});
```

Without any more information about the model you are querying, this should get you what you want.

Make sure you also have the birthday field for the model added to the 
`protected $dates [];` array on the model itself so it automatically get's parsed by `Carbon`.

Comment: if b'day is 16-05-1991, are you sure i'll get results, if we're using between today and (today + 2)

Comment: Updated my code. It SHOULD work now. You may need to change the query so it checks for only models that have birthdays though.

Comment: it doesn't look efficient, does filter run on php or in database ?

Comment: suppose we've 1 billion entries in the database, i don't think it'll be a good idea to fetch 1 billion entries and then filter in php.

Comment: Filter is in php. If you want all this done in db you will need to probably resort to a raw query and use whatever your db's date methods are. Next time you ask a question like this, please be more specific with how you want it done.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Carbon. Example:

```
User::whereBetween('birthday', [Carbon::today(), Carbon::today()->addDays(1)]);
```

If you want to use or, you will need to group them like so:

```
User::where(function($query) {
    $query->whereDate('birthday', Carbon::today())
        ->orWhereBetween('birthday', [Carbon::today(), Carbon::today()->addDays(1)])
        ->orWhereBetween('birthday', [Carbon::today(), Carbon::today()->addDays(2)])
    })->get();
```